# Get URL from <a> tag with php

Tags: php, url

**Hi. I have a string that looks like this:**

```
<a href="https://website.com/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/2020/11/55650-vaikospinta-54vnt-lape.pdf" target="_blank">55650-vaikospinta-54vnt-lape.pdf</a>
```

**I'm trying to pull URL out with PHP, I want result like this:**

```
https://website.com/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/2020/11/55650-vaikospinta-54vnt-lape.pdf
```

Things I've tried:

1. From another StackOverflow question, **I tried this:**

> ```
> $a = new SimpleXMLElement($FileURL);
> $file = 'SimpleXMLElement.txt';
> file_put_contents($file, $a);
> ```

**But result I get** is just the string in between  and , this:

> 55650-vaikospinta-54vnt-lape.pdf

2. Also from another StackOverflow question, **I tried using preg_match, like this:**

> ```
> $file = 'preg_match.txt';
> preg_match_all('/<a[^>]+href=([\'"])(?<href>.+?)\1[^>]*>/i', $FileURL, $result);
>
> if (!empty($result)) {
>     # Found a link.
>     file_put_contents($file, $result);
> }
> ```

I have no idea how regex works (assuming that's regex), but the result I get is just...:

> ArrayArrayArrayArray

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have only the string or the whole HTML document?

Comment: I get this string from a JSON Webhook POST data. So in a way, it's only this string that I get.

Comment: Aside from gambling on copy-pasted answer snippets you've found, what have you done to understand the problem? What have you tried _yourself_ to make this work? Your first example doesn't make much sense and certainly will not give you that output. Advertising that you 'have no idea how regex works' is not a great way to solicit help. Please share some code you've written, and we'll gladly help you debug it.

Comment: What I've tried to do to understand this? Googling, what else is there to do. I tried to come across other people that had the same problem, but thing is, everyone's problem has a little variable that changes the answer every time. "Gambling" - It worked for other people, I thought perhaps it'd be close to my answer. Full code of what exactly? My whole PHP file is getting POST data from JSON Webhook, I'd gladly share it, but I doubt there's anything you can use there to help with the problem. I don't want to burden with more if I don't need to.

Comment: Cheap and dirty: `$result = explode('"', $string)[1];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DOMDocument` with `loadHtml` and `getElementsByTagName` as below

```
$str = '<a href="https://website.com/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/2020/11/55650-vaikospinta-54vnt-lape.pdf" target="_blank">55650-vaikospinta-54vnt-lape.pdf</a>
';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$d=$doc->loadHtml($str);

$a = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($a as $vals) { 
    $href = $vals->getAttribute('href');
   print_r($href); PHP_EOL; 
}
```

if you dont want to use foreach then u can use as  `$href = $a[0]->getAttribute('href');`

> Result will be

```
https://website.com/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/2020/11/55650-vaikospinta-54vnt-lape.pdf
```

Comment: I would prefer `$doc->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');`.

Comment: How should this code look if I had more than one URL seperated by a comma?

Comment: then you need to get using `explode()`

Answer (score 1):

If you insist using regular expression, ie. regex, this works:

```
<?php

$your_var = '<a href="https://website.com/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/2020/11/55650-vaikospinta-54vnt-lape.pdf" target="_blank">55650-vaikospinta-54vnt-lape.pdf</a>';
preg_match('/<a[^>]+href=([\'"])(?<href>.+?)\1[^>]*>/i', $your_var, $result);
$url = $result[2];

echo "Your URL: $url";
```

For example, you can validate your regex online: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Damn, that's a super useful page for regex, thanks for that! However, I can't seem to find what to use in case I have multiple URL's in one string separated by comma?

Comment: @RytisTamošiūnas is this what you are looking for: https://regex101.com/r/vhwQL3/1 ?

Comment: Indeed, you're a godsent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

XPath way:

```
$href = (string) simplexml_load_string($html)->xpath('//a/@href')[0]->href;
```